# How to rewrite a ternary statement in pure JavaScript IF/ELSE

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary

How would I write in pure JavaScript an if/else statement for:

```js
arr = (typeof arr !== "object") ? [arr] : arr;
```

JSLint com keeps saying:
“Wrap a ternary expression in parens, with a line break after the left paren.”
I have tried every possible solution but nothing works. I just want to revert to the pure JavaScript if/else because although I understand the lint warning, it stops any more warnings and it is annoying interrupts my work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). It takes arrays or single elements and turns all into a new array.

```js
console.log([].concat([1, 2, 3]));
console.log([].concat(1));
```

In your example there is no `if` required:

```
arr = [].concat(arr);
```

To avoid the [*JSLint*](https://jslint.com/) warning (abusing Ninas example) you have to follow its guidelines:

```
if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
    array = [array];
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248920/expressions-in-javascript-ternary-operator-and-jslint) is also a topic about it.

Comment: it looks handy but has a drawback, because it creates **always** a new array.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: This is the only solution that avoids the jslint warning and 'seems' to work ok . What does it mean if it creates a new array. What is the new array problem or disadvantage?

Comment: It creates a new array even if the passed parameter already is one, which actually is an unnecessary action and a waste of resources. You will not feel/see a difference, yet it is not really *clean* (=lazy).

Answer (score 0):

if i'm understanding you right, the answer is:

```
if(typeof arr !== "object")
  arr = [arr];
```

notice that there is no real need for the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could check directly for an array.

```
if (!Array.isArray(array)) array = [array];
```